# Centering objects inside of a div using CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get the 3 social sharing buttons beneath the title to center under it (while remaining responsive). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you at least tried googling this?

Comment: add text-align:center to container div

Comment: Yes I've spent 2 hours Googling and messing around with Firebug. Adding text-align center does not work. The closest I get is removing display:inline-block from the 2 sharing buttons container, adding text-align: center -- and that centers those, but it doesn't center the 1st subscribe button, which stays on the left.

Answer (score 2):

`.OptIn-SubButton{display:inline-block;}` and remove the float rule form it. And for the `.optIn-top{text-align:center;}`

Comment: I removed float rule from the sub button, added the inline block display, added text align center for the optin-top and it didn't center anything... Did you verify this? Thank you

Comment: Very sure! Tested it in inspector

Comment: Okay I added it to style sheet and it did work. Thank you! Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `width`, and `margin: 0 auto;` on your button container.

```
.optIn-top {
  /* [existing stuff] */
  width: 582px; /* Adjust this for smaller devices */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```